# Re-enable Same Origin Policy on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium, same-origin-policy

At some point, I seemed to have somehow disabled the same origin policy on one of my Chrome profiles. For instance, while on https://www.google.com, I am able to successfully execute the below in the console and get the full response:

```
function reqListener () {
  console.log(this.responseText);
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
oReq.open("GET", "https://www.yahoo.com");
oReq.send();
```

On my other chrome profiles, this code gives the expected error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.yahoo.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.google.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

How can I re-enable the SOP for my chrome profile?

---

Please note that I am not using the `--disable-web-security` tag (at least not knowingly). I am opening the raw executable directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, your shortcut may have the `--disable-web-security` explicitly set at the end of the Target path. Right click on the shortcut, and under the Shortcut tab, make sure there is nothing after the path to the executable.

If you are using a Mac, I think you would have used an `AppleScript` launcher to run Chrome with the flag set, if you're not running via Terminal.

You should also check that you haven't got an extension installed that is disabling it, e.g. [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en). Otherwise, I recommend simply resetting your profile completely, as I don't see any way of it being disabled.

Comment: I'm using windows and I checked the shortcut - the flag was not there. I also specifically opened directly from the actual .exe and had the same result

Comment: @wlingke Check that you haven't got an extension installed that is disabling it, e.g. Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *. Otherwise I recommend simply resetting your profile. I don't see any way of it being disabled.